# How can I get video duration by using vimeo javascript API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo

I am having a premium channel on vimeo. I am trying to put a list of videos and their duration on my website. They have an example by using the event listeners. But as I am interested in simple text output of video duration. So How can I do it ?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I am first time on stackoverflow. I have pasted the code below.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getDuration()` from the [Vimeo player javascript API](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/blob/master/README.md):

```
player.getDuration().then(function(duration) {
    // duration = the duration of the video in seconds
}).catch(function(error) {
    // an error occurred
});
```

Source: https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/blob/master/README.md#getduration-promisenumber-error

Answer (score 0):

```
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
  const player = new Player(iframe);
  
  player.loadVideo(123456).then(() => {
    player.ready().then(() => {
      player.getDuration().then((data) => console.log(data));
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

(function () {
        var vimeoPlayers = document.querySelectorAll('iframe'), player;

        for (var i = 0, length = vimeoPlayers.length; i